# Based on items checked, create list of emails from form

Tags: c#, forms, email

I have a simple form on a webpage which gives the user the choice to send the page form to up to 4 different email recipients via checkboxes. Here is the code for the 4 choices, note that two of them are dropdowns.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkdnr" Text="DNR" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="check_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="checksenate" Text="Senate Rep" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="check_CheckedChanged" />

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="listSenate">
  <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Choose your representative" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="senator 1" Value="senator1@email.com" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="senator 2" Value="senator2@email.com" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="senator 3" Value="senator3@email.com" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:CheckBox ID="checkcongress" Text="Congress Rep" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="check_CheckedChanged" />

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="listCongress">
  <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Choose your representative" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="congress 1" Value="congress1@email.com" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="congress 2" Value="congress2@email.com" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="congress 3" Value="congress3@email.com" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:CheckBox ID="checkgov" Text="Governor" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="check_CheckedChanged" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtBody" runat="server" Height="171px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="270px" />

<asp:Button ID="Btn_SendMail" runat="server" OnClick="Btn_SendMail_Click" Text="Send Email" />

<asp:Label ID="status" runat="server" Text="" />
<asp:Label ID="emails" runat="server" Text="" />
```

So basically I would like to create a function in the code-behind to print out the 'string' of selected emails on the front-end here for testing purposes. Perhaps also throwing them into a hidden form variable which I can pass to the Submit function once the user is ready to send the message.

I guess my question is what is the best way to approach this, js on the front-end and do a foreach loop and check for values there and put that value into a hidden input? ... or on the back-end and just handle it all in the code-behind.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What is your question, then? Have at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all in back-end, to get values of dropdown u can use "listSenate.SelectedValue.ToString()" and "listCongress.SelectedValue.ToString()"

to the checkbox ou can use if(checkcongress.Checked){ code here }

after, you can create a string of emails and send using Net.Mail and Net.Mime

if you dont know how send email with c# i can show you my code.